# Looking for subquery in THEN but just always get result set error

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select
  rn,
  ps_name,
  lot,
  wo_num
from
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY lot
        ORDER BY
          ps_name
      ) AS rn,
      ps_name,
      lot,
      wo_num
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          ps_name,
          mfgdate,
          CASE
            WHEN substr(ps_name, 7, 1) = 'A'
            AND ab_split = 'A' THEN substr(ps_name, 1, 6)
            ELSE substr(ps_name, 1, 6)
          END lot,
          side,
          wo_num
        FROM
          table
        WHERE
          side = 'TO'
      )
  )
```

which gives the following output:

```
RN | PS_NAME | LOT    | WO_NUM
-------------------------------
1  | ANW217  | ANW217 | 4897524
1  | ANW218  | ANW218 | 5041093
1  | ANW219  | ANW219 | 5064069
2  | ANW219A | ANW219 | 5064097
1  | ANW220  | ANW220 | 5064070
2  | ANW220A | ANW220 | 5064098
1  | ANW221  | ANW221 | 5064071
2  | ANW221A | ANW221 | 5064099
```

Desired outcome:

```
PS_NAME | LOT    | WO_NUM
--------------------------
ANW217   | ANW217 | 4897524
ANW218   | ANW218 | 5041093
ANW219   | ANW219 | 5064069
ANW219A  | ANW219 | 5064069
ANW220   | ANW220 | 5064070
ANW220A  | ANW220 | 5064070
ANW221   | ANW221 | 5064071
ANW221A  | ANW221 | 5064071
```

Note, when there's an A in PS_NAME then I want the WO_NUM from PS_NAME without the 'A', e.g. ANW219A but give me WO_NUM from ANW219, and so on.

Whenever I try this logic within the select part as CASE WHEN + subquery in THEN clause, I get the error that it's not giving a scalar but result set. I know, but I just don't have any clue how to solve it. This seems so easy and yet I don't make any progress.

Is there any other window function that might be more suitable? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: `min(wo_num) over (partition by lot)`?

Comment: `first_value(wo_num) over (partition by lot order by ps_name)`

Comment: yes, does the job, smart move, thanks. post it as answer please so we get it documented :)___:                     FIRST_VALUE(wo_num)
                    OVER(PARTITION BY lot
                         ORDER BY
                             ps_name
                    ) AS rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `wo_num` from the first row in each lot by order of `ps_name`.

```
first_value(wo_num) over (partition by lot order by ps_name)
```